# Not targetting the latest versions of Android warning

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting this warning in my Android app manifest file. I have tried everything, but this just doesn't go away. I am trying to use Accelerometer and Magnetometer in my ap and added the additional permissions  Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.msapp2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <!--  need for streaming video + about page -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <!--  need for reminder add/delete -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mainicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.msapp2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".WorkoutBuddy"
            android:label="exercise" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.exercise" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written latest version as `android:targetSdkVersion="18"` ( Android 4.3 ) in your manifest.xml file, But I assume you have latest version in your SDK, probably `19`the version.

Since it is just a Warning, so you can ignore if you are not targeting your application to `Kitkat` version ( 4.4.2 ).

Otherwise solution is to change it to `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

Comment: @user3000837 ,did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

EDIT: [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

The docs are a little fuzzy, but what they say is that the target SDK version is used to determine if android should enable compatibility layers. for example, If your min SDK was 8, but your target SDK was 19, you are telling android that while there's no reason it shouldn't work on version 8, you've only tested on 19. Therefore, if there any compatibility settings to enable between level 8 and 19, they can be set. note that this attribute may actually do nothing depending on the actual min / target values.

If you set min SDK == target, you are essentially saying you have tested on the lowest API level you claim to support, which is a good thing.

Comment: Are you able to expand on this answer, perhaps explain why this will (or might) solve the problem? Just pasting code sometimes isn't very helpful.

Comment: As a developer any one can understand what i mean in my copy past. and  @RowanFreeman why you care about copy and past ?

Comment: Anyone can read it and understand it, I agree, but it's nice to have an explanation for code when you post it. It's *showing your work* and it helps others who might stumble upon this answer one day. Your answer was flagged as a low-quality answer. Rather than voting to close, I figured asking you to improve it would not require closure.

Comment: @RowanFreeman please edit my answer if i am mistaken, thanks for your feedback